# Slicing a dataframe according to the groups, with no consecutive strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with questionary results for different countries, with repeated entries for each country. The countries are found in v6. For example:

```
v1   v2 ... v6     ...  v550
0    5  ... Belgium...  not important
1    6  ... Belgium...  important
.
.
.
1002  5 ... Belgium ... do not care
1003  3 ... Germany ... important
```

I know how to extract the data from Belgium

```
print ('Belgium')
groupBE = dataframe[(dataframe['v6']=='Belgium')]
print ('what is the importance in Belgium')
cforBE = groupBE['v550'].value_counts(sort = False)
print (cforBE)
```

I was wondering if there is an elegant way for doing the same operation over the 26 countries found in v6 without having to write the code for all. I assume that it has to do with `groupby()`, since this one gives me the different values for v6. And `itertools` is often quoted in forums, but I dont get it to work. The closest I've got is by temporarly saving and printing the countries in `locals()`, or the code below, but none of them work because I dont know how to make a variable change name

```
for name, group in dataframe.groupby('v6'):
    print (name)
    c + str(name) = dataframe[(dataframe['v6']=='name')]
    print ('importance in country ' name)
    c + str(name) = c + str(name) ['v550'].value_counts(sort = False)
    print (c + str (name))
```

Comment: Can't you just, in the last piece of code, write `dataframe[(dataframe['v6']==name)]` instead?

Answer (score 1):

What about iterating over the different countries?  Then go through the same procedure with each country

```
for country in dataframe['v6'].unique():
    group = dataframe[dataframe['v6'] == country] #.copy()
    print group['v550'].value_counts(sort=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Just had to change a couple of things. `for country in dataframe['v6'].unique():
    group = dataframe[(dataframe['v6'] == country)].copy()
    print (group['v550'].value_counts(sort=False))`

Comment: @AFF why did you need to make either of those changes? Parentheses inside `df[(df['v6'] == country)]` are only needed when using multiple expressions inside the slice.  Are you using python3?  If so, `print()` is a function and there is no need for the space in between it and the parentheses.

Comment: I am using Python 3.5 , but through Spyder. By programming in Spyder I needed the `print()`. You are right, if I type it on the console I do not need the print function. The same goes to the extra parentheses I needed for the `df[(df['v6'] == country)]`, I do not need it when typing directly on the console. Sorry for the confusion and thanks again for the help. :)